# How to install JavaCV on Android and use FrameGrabber

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

Could someone tell me where I'm doing wrong? These are the steps that I have followed:

1. Downloaded the adt-bundle-windows from android developer website
2. Created a new project and a libs/armeabi folder
3. Extract all the *.so files from javacv-android-arm.jar, opencv-2.4.3-android-arm.zip, and ffmpeg-1.0-android-arm.zip directly into the newly created "libs/armeabi" folder, without creating any new subdirectories.

   (A part that I don't understand is *"Extract all the *.so files from javacv-android-arm.jar"*, I simply inserted the javacv-android-arm.jar file inside libs/armeabi folder)
4. Navigated to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and click "Add JARs...".
5. Selected both javacpp.jar and javacv.jar from the newly created "libs" folder.

After that I have downloaded OpenCV2.4.3 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.3/OpenCV-2.4.3.exe/download) and ffmpeg from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/shared/ffmpeg-20121029-git-11d695d-win64-shared.7z) and extracted the files on my C:/ root.
Finally after setting my system path...,

```
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin;C:\ffmpeg-64\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin
```

...if I try to use simply FrameGrabber in my Android application...

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.*;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        FFmpegFrameGrabber i = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("/mnt/sdcard/SinglePerson.avi"); 
    }
```

...I get the following errors:

```
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at com.example.xxxxxxxxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-29 17:59:26.976: E/AndroidRuntime(30656):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 12):

So a jar file is basically a zip file, if you change the extension to ".zip" you can extract the files it contains like you did with OpenCV and FFMPEG.

So, rename  "javacv-android-arm.jar" to " javacv-android-arm.zip," extract the .so files out of it and copy them to libs/armeabi.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried to include also the other .so files but the problem remains.

Comment: Ok Ok I solved... the problem was that I inserted the jar file inside libs/armeabi instead of libs. X-(

Answer (score 2):

Gradle:

`compile 'org.bytedeco:javacv:1.0'
    compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:2.4.11-0.11:android-x86'
    compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:2.6.1-0.11:android-x86'
    compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:2.4.11-0.11:android-arm'
    compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:2.6.1-0.11:android-arm'`

this will integrate javacv to android

Answer (score 0):

Use this example:

http://javacv4android.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/how-to-import-javacv-libraries-to.html

later in OnCreate:

```
try {
        FrameGrabber grabber2 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/TESTE/spell.mp3");

        String t = "!";

        grabber2 = null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

if don't exist error, it's ok =)

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

For latest version.
In `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
...
   mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
...
   compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.2'
   compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version:   '3.1.0-1.2', classifier: 'android-arm'
   compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version:   '3.1.2-1.2', classifier: 'android-arm'
}
configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'javacpp-presets'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who come last.

in the build gradle **(module:app)

add this code on it.

```
    dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.5.8'
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).